# How to plot several line charts in one figure (overlay/groupby)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization

I would like to illustrate the change in one variable for several persons in my data over time. I have several issues with basic commands here.

Here is my data:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': ['1988', '1989', '1990', '1988', '1989', '1990', '1988', '1989', '1990'],
                   'id': ['1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3'],
                   'money': ['5', '7', '8', '8', '3', '3', '7', '8', '10']}).astype(int)

df.info()
df
```

I tried to make use of `matplotlib` and started to loop for each of my unique IDs. I'm new to this package. First, how can I specify for each plot that only 3 points are connected for a line, not all? Second, how can I overlay those plots in one figure?

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i in df.id.unique():
        df.plot.line(x='year', y='money')
```

Comment: Hi Marco, Could you please be more specific about your question? It would be nice if you post a sketch of your end result

Comment: I will post a sketch of my goal next time. There are already several perfect answers. I will try to extend the code from this starting point. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have tagged `matplotlib`, one solution is to  check for the `id` while looping through the DataFrame before plotting using `df[df['id']==i]`.

To overlay those plots in one figure, create a figure object and pass the axis `ax` to the `df.plot()` function.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': ['1988', '1989', '1990', '1988', '1989', '1990', '1988', '1989', '1990'],
                   'id': ['1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3'],
                   'money': ['5', '7', '8', '8', '3', '3', '7', '8', '10']}).astype(int)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for i in df.id.unique():
    df[df['id']==i].plot.line(x='year', y='money', ax=ax, label='id = %s'%i)
plt.xticks(np.unique(df.year),rotation=45)
```

[image]

**Pandas solution** using `groupby` would look like following. Here you will have to modify the legends later.

```
df.groupby('id').plot(x='year', y='money',legend=True, ax=ax)

h,l = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(h, df.id.unique(), fontsize=12)
plt.xticks(np.unique(df.year), rotation=45)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use either `groupby`:

```
df.set_index('year').groupby('id').money.plot()
```

which gives:

[image]

or, use `seaborn` with `hue`

```
sns.lineplot(x='year',y='money', hue='id', data=df)
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: Nice solution with the seaborn. Any idea where this id=0 is coming from?

Comment: My guess it’s a seaborn bug that always starts numeric hue from `0`. Should go away by converting to categorical hue.

Comment: Adding `legend='full'` seems to address this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Can also be done with a simple `pivot`

```
df.pivot(index='year', columns='id', values='money').plot(rot=45)
```

[image]

If some entries are missing years, then this will not plot perfectly, so add an interpolation:

```
(df.pivot(index='year', columns='id', values='money')
   .apply(pd.Series.interpolate, limit_area='inside')
   .plot())
```