# Plot pandas dataframe values by multiple criteria

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following dataframe:

```
data = [
    ['unit1','A',3000,2.4],['unit1','A',4000,2.5],['unit1','A',5000,2.7],
    ['unit2','A',3000,2.1],['unit2','A',4000,2.3],['unit2','A',5000,2.6],
    ['unit3','A',3000,2.5],['unit3','A',4000,2.6],['unit3','A',5000,2.8]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['unitname','channel','frequency','power'])
```

I would like to plot power over frequency, with each unit its own series and a legend corresponding to the unit name.  With putting all of the series in the same plot.

Comment: I think what you want is already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56632446/how-to-plot-several-line-charts-in-one-figure-overlay-groupby

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Use [`seaborn`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/) to make your plots look nicer:

- Using the sample dataframe provided in the question.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
sns.lineplot(x='power', y='frequency', data=df, hue='unitname')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

IICU, this is what you need

```
df[df['unitname']=='unit1'].plot(x="power", y="frequency",title='unit1',colormap='Reds_r')
df[df['unitname']=='unit2'].plot(x="power", y="frequency",title='unit2', colormap='Blues_r')
df[df['unitname']=='unit3'].plot(x="power", y="frequency",title='unit3', colormap='Greens_r')
```

[image]